# Is it possible to combine a 1d Excel VBA array with a 2d Array

Tags: excel, vba

I have two arrays:

```
Dim arrA(1, 5) Variant
Dim arrB(10, 5) Variant
```

I would like to combine arrays A & B to create array C, a new 10 by 10 array.

Comment: arrA has 1 row and 5 columns. arrB has 10 rows and 5 columns. If you make arrC that has 10 rows, arrB's 10 rows will consume all of the rows. Where will arrA's row go? If arrC had 11 rows, you can fit arrA and B's rows in it. arrA and B have 5 columns. How would you fill arrC's 10 columns? Would you dump arrA's columns in col 1-5 and arrB's columns in 6-10?

Comment: @zedfoxus Array C would have  10 rows and 10 columns. As you suggested Arr B would be the base of Arr C initially 10 rows and 5 columns, next column 1 through 5 of array A would become columns 6 through 10 for each of the 10 rows of Arra C.

Comment: So what's the problem?  You can do this using a loop.  Note you have 2 2-d arrays though, not one 2-d and one 1-d array.  Also since the default lbound is zero your new 10x10 would leave out one row from arrB

Comment: Note that your code is missing 2 `As` right before `Variant` like `Dim arrA(1, 5) As Variant`.